# Any client side RichText Editor like DevExpress RichEdit

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, client-server, editor

last two weeks, i researched richtext component to use our application in our company. Now, we use ckeditor but we want to change it more beautiful component on ui side. I integrated Devexpress richeditor with mvc in our application but it was server sided component and it does not fit for requirements on client side. Because we need to make some jobs on client side with text editor. The question is, is there any client sided richtext editor "LIKE DEVEXPRESS RICHEDIT" in ui. There are some editors, e.g "txcontrol" "fckeditor", "tinymce", "markitup" and etc. But the main thing is, the client sided components does not split the pages. Do you know any component? We are using "asp.net mvc and angular.js" Thansk for advice...

Answer (score 1):

The newest DevExpress Web RichEdit version is now completely client-side/JavaScript based.

It can be used in a pure JS code or within any framework (such as the jQuery or [Angular](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNetCore/401527/office-inspired-controls/controls/rich-edit/angular)).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this because you are using angularjs http://textangular.com/

Or Telerik Kendo UI text editor http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/index

Comment: I know this component, but in ui, this does not split the pages like devexpress or word... So i don't understand document contains how many page as end user. Thanks anyway.

Comment: also you can check Telerik Kendo UI mentioned in answer update may it would help you

Comment: I know this too. Telerik RadEditor does not split pages too.